# My browsers won't use my full screen resolution and also use different resolutions between them

Tags: google-chrome, browser, windows-8.1, internet-explorer, resolution

[image: chrome]

[image: ie]

My screen resolution is actually 3200x1800, but when I'm in a browser it acts like I have a smaller resolution. How do I get my browsers to use my full resolution?

On Chrome it's using 1280x720, and on IE it's using 1600x900. According to whatismyscreenresolution.com, which is showing different values for different browsers. I took a screenshot of them and verified that my resolution is 3200x1800 as that is the pixels in the bitmap.

I'm on a laptop with no monitor plugged in. My zoom in both browsers is at 100%. I've tried zooming out below 100% but then the text is unreadable and pixellated. I've tried restarting. Windows 8.1. I've tried the chrome extension OptiZoom and it does nothing. document.body.clientWidth gives 1247, and I want it to give 3200.

Comment: Try http://whatis.myscreenresolution.com/ it can detect the correct resolution even if you're on a hidpi monitor

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - It's actually [whatismyscreenresolution.com](http://whatismyscreenresolution.com/).  You have an extra `.` in there.

Comment: @Bobson no it's actually a different website. http://whatismyscreenresolution.com/ cannot detect the real resolution while http://whatis.myscreenresolution.com/ can display the correct resolution when you're in hidpi mode like the OP

Comment: Fun fact: the screenshot from this question is featured in the film "The Clapper" (2017), about 46 minutes in.

Comment: My icons are famous! LOL in the movie he's searching google but the browser URL says whatismyscreenresolution.com Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Possible Problem**

This is most likely an issue caused by [Window 8.1 "Display Scaling" feature](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx). See [a relevant post in the Google Chrome forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_CJ-5YHCixY).

**Possible Solution**

Try disabling this feature for your browsers. For example, locate the Chrome executable which is commonly found in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%/Google/Chrome/Application/`. Right click the file, select "Properties" and then under the "Compatibility" tab tick the box saying "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"

[image]

Comment: Woah, I'm so dumb. I changed the settings of my display and forgot about it. Later on,  updating the project to fix the resolution issue,

Answer (score 6):

Well, it’s pretty obvious this is yet another example of DPI scaling gone horribly wrong.

Chrome is party to blame too. According to [this article](http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-google-chrome-hidpi-support-windows/), there are (well, were) some possible workarounds.

- Disable DPI scaling in Chrome’s compatibility settings (Properties on executable or shortcuts)—last resort “solution”
- Go to chrome://flags and enable experimental Windows HiDPI support. (*Gone now, apparently*)
- Load the following `.reg` file:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\Profile]
  "high-dpi-support"=dword:00000001
  ```

A word of warning though: HiDPI is under development and has issues. If you cannot live with that, I suggest you try an alternate browser like Firefox. It’s supposed to have better DPI scaling support.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Windows 10,

1. Go to Start button > Settings > Ease of Access > Display.
2. Set "Make everything bigger" to 100%.

[See here the screenshot of above Settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCE5W.png).

(Note: However keeping it to recommended settings gives you more readable texts across different applications.)

Answer (score -1):

Remember that display resolution is configurable, it's different from native resolution.

Another better choice is http://myscreenchecker.com, not only check for screen display resolution, but also for checking your screen color, screen health with 15 basic color, including: black, white, red, green, blue, ...

Comment: Are you affiliated with the software in that link? Unsolicited advertisements will be deleted as spam.