# High-dpi settings for chrome on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, high-resolution

On a high-reslution screen with firefox, you can set in `about:config`

```
layout.css.devPixelsPerPx=2
```

so everything in Firefox has double size.

Is there such a setting for chrome-browser as well?

Comment: The unfortunate truth: Chrome doesn’t do High DPI. [See here](http://superuser.com/q/762956/219095) for example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `google-chrome` in Linux, and what worked for me was editing the launcher so that it passes the command line argument `--force-device-scale-factor=2`

e.g. in /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

```
# ...
# Make sure that the profile directory specified in the environment, if any,
# overrides the default.
if [[ -n "$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" ]]; then
  # Note: exec -a below is a bashism.
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  \
    --force-device-scale-factor=2 \
    --user-data-dir="$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" "$@"
else
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" \
    --force-device-scale-factor=2 \
    "$@"
fi
```

See [Chrome UI size & zoom levels in Ubuntu 16.04](https://superuser.com/questions/1116767/chrome-ui-size-zoom-levels-in-ubuntu-16-04)