# Chrome Maximize button greyed out and not working

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Suddenly on some of our computers the Chrome browser Maximize button at top right of the browser is greyed out and does not work. We can still maximize/unmaximize by double-clicking the header, and the Minimize and Close buttons are present and function properly. It doesn't seem to matter what page we have open or what site we are on. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome, flushing the cache, and disabling all of the extensions. This is a Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have seen a very similar issue to this recently on a few users. I came across a [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/j8vc37/touch_ui_flag_users_experiencing_bugs_my/) where someone else mentioned the issue was with "Touch UI", We also found that this was the case, after disabling Touch UI and restarting chrome the buttons were no longer greyed-out. I suspect a recent google update has changed how this behaves.

To change Touch UI settings in Google Chrome:

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Enter `chrome://flags` in the address bar
3. Search for "Touch UI Layout"
4. Ensure Touch UI is disabled or set to default

**NOTE: You will need to restart google chrome for this to take affect.**

Comment: Yup -- that did it!

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: disabling works for windows 11

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on a MS Surface Pro 7. I think because this is a touchscreen PC this somehow disabled the maximize button on Chrome. Not sure though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1115082)