# How to adjust UI scaling for Chrome on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, high-resolution

Similar to [How to adjust UI scaling for Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1139259/how-to-adjust-ui-scaling-for-chrome?newreg=6fc47078009e4fc38fec04d7e92b2da3) I would like to learn if there is an option to increase chrome UI (not just a page content, but search bar/extensions/bookmarks/tabs) on a monitor with high ppi.

I'm getting 2x retina experience on my monitor and it is nice, but small chrome UI text is not great.

I tried playing with `--force-device-scale-factor` and checked `chrome://flags`, but no luck so far.

[An example of the experience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W8rs.png)

To clarify, I would like to avoid whole system scaling (controlled via displays setting) as that makes all text appear blurry and defeats a purpose of retina screen.